# Почему ставится запятая в предложении "Собранные влажными, они постоянно портятся"?

Tags: синтаксис

Почему здесь нужно ставить запятую?

> Собранные влажными, они постоянно портятся.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая в вашем случае регламентируется следующим правилом:

> Определение, относящееся к личному местоимению, обособляется
> независимо от степени его распространенности и местоположения:
> *Убаюканный сладкими надеждами, он крепко спал* (Ч.); *Низенький,
> коренастый, он обладал страшною силою в руках* (М. Г).

(См. [Розенталь "Пунктуация", § 18_1 п. 10](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108))

Comment: Наверно, надо убрать цифру 1 после § 18.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец нет, всё верно. 18-й параграф делится на 18_1 (согласованные определения) и 18_2 (несогласованные определения). Каждая из этих частей делится ещё на ряд пунктов и подпунктов. Даже в перекрёстных ссылках между справочниками Розенталя и Лопатина так пишется: https://i.imgur.com/P5xLA7R.png